# Is there a list of math delimiters?

Tags: luatex, delimiters

I recently discovered that the double square brackets `\llbracket` and `\rrbracket` from `stmaryrd` are available as unicode characters ⟦ and ⟧, which makes them easy to use with LuaLaTex.I was even more pleased to realize that those work with `\left`, `\bigl` etc. without any further `DeclareMathDelimiter` sorcery, they are already recognised as delimiters. That means I can write

```
\[ \left⟦ \sum \right⟧ \]
```

and get

[image]

So I wondered, is there some list of all math delimiters that are recognized out of the box?

Comment: They are listed in the “Comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols”, `texdoc comprehensive`.

Comment: @egreg That lists them as part of the `stmaryrd` package. My point is that they even work without the package, and I wondered what other delimiters might work. I tried to clarify this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As egreg mentioned in a comment, a list of delimiters can be found in the ["Comprehensive list of LaTeX symbols", `texdoc comprehensive`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf). This list contains all symbols that work out of the box, even for LuaLaTeX.

Using math delimiters which are accessible as Unicode characters sounds like you are using the `unicode-math` package. This package provides a lot of additional delimiters (and other symbols) which are listed in ["Symbols defined by `unicode-math`", `texdoc unimath`](http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf). Of these, all symbols from the categories "Opening symbols, `\mathopen`", "Closing symbols, `\mathclose`" and "Fence symbols `\mathfence`" are set up as delimiters. (For the fences, there are additional left and right variants prefixed with `l` or `r`)

The precise list which delimiters you can use also depends on your font: For example the default Unicode Math font "Latin Modern Math" doesn't provide most symbols which aren't accessible from traditional LaTeX but this can be seen in the list too.